# Why can you access angular ngOnChanges SimpleChange property directly from SimpleChange object without using index

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I am using ngOnChanges and I've set the SimpleChange parameter as below.  Why is it that I can directly access my input property using changes.currentValue without having to get the property using indexing?  Both work and I'm confused as to why?

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called with changes value: ', changes.currentValue) // why does this work? is it because by convention it works if I have just one input property??
   
    for (const propName in changes) {
      console.log('ngOnChanges called with propName value: ', changes[propName].currentValue)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declaring the `changes` parameter with the `SimpleChange` type but according to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) they should be of type `SimpleChanges`(note the 's' at the end);

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes['YOUR_PROP'].currentValue);
}
```

Comment: Aaaa! That's a typo, but then that makes me wonder why am still able to use the for loop on the changes param if it is just a single object?  I still get the full object and can access it's keys when I do changes[propName] inside the for loop.